# iterative definition of functions in Python

Tags: python, list, function, redefinition

I am getting crazy with this kind of problem:

I have a list of string representing functions (for eval), I need first to replace the variables with generic `x[0], x[1],...`.

Some time ago I discovered that I can do this using `subs()`. Then I need to generate a list of functions (to define constraints in SciPy minimize).
I am trying something like:

```
el=[budget.v.values()[0],silly.v.values()[0]] # my list of string/equations

fl=[]
for i in range(len(el)):
    def sos(v):
        vdict = dict(zip(q.v.values(),v)) 
        return eval(el[i]).subs(vdict)
    fl.append(sos) 
    del sos # this may be unnecessary
```

The result for fl is:

```
[<function sos at 0x19a26aa28>, <function sos at 0x199e3f398>]
```

but the two functions always give the same result (corresponding to the last 'sos' definition). How can I retain different function definitions?

Comment: _"but the two functions always give the same result (corresponding to the last 'sos' definition)"_ that is because `i` is captured by name and so when `sos()` is invoked `i` will have the final value. See [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures)

Answer (score 2):

Your comment:

> but the two functions always give the same result (corresponding to the last 'sos' definition)

Is a big clue that you've likely run into this [common gotcha](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures)!

Your code isn't in a runnable form so I can't verify this but it clearly has this bug.  There are various ways to fix this including using [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) as explained in the first link.

For example (untested as your code isn't runnable as-is):

```
import functools

for i in range(len(el)):
    def sos(i, v):
        vdict = dict(zip(q.v.values(),v)) 
        return eval(el[i]).subs(vdict)
    fl.append(functools.partial(sos, i))
```

Given this you can now refactor this code to avoid redefining the function inside the loop:

```
def sos(i, v):
    vdict = dict(zip([2], v))
    return eval(el[i]).subs(vdict)

for i in range(len(el)):
   fl.append(functools.partial(sos, i))
```

To give you a complete and runnable example:

```
import functools

def add_x(x, v):
    return x + v

add_5 = functools.partial(add_x, 5)
print add_5(1)
```

Produces:

```
6
```

Comment: Thank You very much for the hint! I understood that this is due to the "late binding closure". Great Help!